# cassandra nosql autorestart service with chkserv.d

Tags: linux, service, centos, cassandra, background-process

I don't have much of linux experience, so it might be I'm missing something obvious.

However... I'm trying to put Cassandra nosql in chkserv.d on CentOS so it is autorestarted when it breaks. I managed to put it there and it is correctly recognized by chkservd when it breaks. I put it like this:

```
root@server [/etc/chkserv.d]# cat cassandra
service[cassandra]=x,x,x,/etc/init.d/cassandra start,cassandra,root
```

The problem is when that 'cassandra start' is executed, in cassandra.out log I get:

```
 /opt/cassandra/cassandra_home/bin/cassandra: line 141: exec: java: not found
```

In line 141 of cassandra script is:

exec $NUMACTL "$JAVA" $JVM_OPTS $cassandra_parms -cp "$CLASSPATH" $props "$class" <&- &

And all environment variables are correctly expanded:

```
java -ea -javaagent:/opt/cassandra/cassandra_home/bin/../lib/jamhreadPriorities -XX:ThreadPriorityPolicy=42 -Xms400M -Xmx400M -XnOutOfMemoryError -Xss180k -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweeemarkEnabled -XX:SurvivorRatio=8 -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=1 -XX:yFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -Djava.net.prefe.sun.management.jmxremote.port=7199 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremon.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dlog4j.configuration=es -Dlog4j.defaultInitOverride=true -Dcassandra-pidfile=/var/runpt/cassandra/cassandra_home/bin/../conf:/opt/cassandra/cassandraasses/main:/opt/cassandra/cassandra_home/bin/../build/classes/thassandra_home/bin/../lib/antlr-3.2.jar:/opt/cassandra/cassandra_e-cassandra-1.1.5.jar:/opt/cassandra/cassandra_home/bin/../lib/atutil-1.1.5.jar:/opt/cassandra/cassandra_home/bin/../lib/apache-5.jar:/opt/cassandra/cassandra_home/bin/../lib/avro-1.4.0-fixes.ssandra_home/bin/../lib/avro-1.4.0-sources-fixes.jar:/opt/cassann/../lib/commons-cli-1.1.jar:/opt/cassandra/cassandra_home/bin/..2.jar:/opt/cassandra/cassandra_home/bin/../lib/commons-lang-2.4assandra_home/bin/../lib/compress-lzf-0.8.4.jar:/opt/cassandra/clib/concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru-1.3.jar:/opt/cassandra/cassandraa-r08.jar:/opt/cassandra/cassandra_home/bin/../lib/high-scale-liandra/cassandra_home/bin/../lib/jackson-core-asl-1.9.2.jar:/opt/ome/bin/../lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.2.jar:/opt/cassandra/cassajamm-0.2.5.jar:/opt/cassandra/cassandra_home/bin/../lib/jline-0.ra/cassandra_home/bin/../lib/json-simple-1.1.jar:/opt/cassandra//lib/libthrift-0.7.0.jar:/opt/cassandra/cassandra_home/bin/../lipt/cassandra/cassandra_home/bin/../lib/metrics-core-2.0.3.jar:/oa_home/bin/../lib/servlet-api-2.5-20081211.jar:/opt/cassandra/caib/slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar:/opt/cassandra/cassandra_home/bin/../lib/ar:/opt/cassandra/cassandra_home/bin/../lib/snakeyaml-1.6.jar:/oa_home/bin/../lib/snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar:/opt/cassandra/cassandaptree-0.1.jar org.apache.cassandra.thrift.CassandraDaemon
```

When I start that cassandra script manually, or go and start it with etc/init.d/cassandra start, everything is started correctly.

Million dollar question - what am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: Just needed to set JAVA_HOME environment variable. Now everything works as expected.

Comment: FYI: you can answer your own questions and accept the answers.  For anybody else hitting this, I suggest setting JAVA_HOME in /etc/default/cassandra.  That's the typical place for setting up environment variables for init scripts.

Comment: Thanks for info. I tried that now and it is not working. Created "cassandra" file in /etc/default and put JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/jdk there but now it says "not found" again, as stated in question. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just needed to set JAVA_HOME environment variable. Now everything works as expected.

Uncommented line in $CASSANDRA_HOME/bin/cassandra.in.sh.